# opening multiple tabs in firefox using a one-liner bash script

Tags: bash, firefox

I am on CentOS 6.6.  I have a program that runs analysis and outputs its data in html files.

The file structure is

```
dir1/dir1.html
dir2/dir2.html
dir3/dir3.html
```

I want to open all three html files from a bash one liner, e.g.

```
for i in dir*; do firefox --new-tab $i/${i}.html; done
```

This opens the files individually, such that the first html file must be closed before the second one opens.  If I try to send it as a background process, e.g.

```
 for i in dir*; do firefox --new-tab $i/${i}.html&; done
```

I get:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

I also tried the same method as in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17659/opening-multiple-urls-from-a-text-file-as-different-tabs-in-firefox-chrome) post, but it still opens them individually.

How can I open these all in the same tab using a little bash one-liner?

Comment: `&` ends the command, so you don't need the `;`

Comment: @drewbenn I don't see that it's a duplicate?

Comment: @drewbenn `&&` doesn't (just) terminate a command; it separates two commands. `&` and `;` are both terminators that don't explicitly require a subsequent command

Comment: Quote, quote, always quote: Use `firefox '--new-tab' "$i/${i}"'.html&';` if you want to include the &. Use `firefox '--new-tab' "$i/${i}"'.html' &` (no `;`) as the `&` already signals the end of the command.

Answer (score -1):

My solution requires that firefox is already running, if not, start it with firefox &. Then this script will open up the pages in tabs

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in dir*; do
  firefox $i
done
```

I am using firefox 38.4.0