# How to sequentially open URLs in lynx?

Tags: url, lynx

from `$ man lynx` page:

> If  more  than  one  local  file or remote URL is listed on the command line, Lynx will open only the last interactively.  All of the names (local files and remote URLs) are added to the G)oto history.

Since I prefer not having to manually move between documents (`G)oto history`), I'm currently using xargs to send multiple URLs (in a text file, one per line) in order to sequentially open all in lynx:

```
xargs --max-lines=1 lynx < URLs.txt
```

In lynx, press <kbd>Q</kbd> twice to proceed to the next webpage.

Directly opening several URLs opens the last one interactively, as mentioned on the man page:

```
lynx https://example.com/ https://example.net/ https://example.org/ https://example.edu/
```

---

related questions:

[opening multiple URLs from a text file as different tabs in Firefox/Chrome?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17659/opening-multiple-urls-from-a-text-file-as-different-tabs-in-firefox-chrome)
[How to open several local (HTML) documents in lynx?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703399/how-to-open-several-local-html-documents-in-lynx/)

Comment: I don't understand what's the question. What do you want to achieve? What's wrong with the commands shown in the question? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Bodo Nothing, I asked for clarification about the built-in support in lynx.

Comment: From the question it is not clear what you achieve. You show two commands that do different things, and you cite the documentation that explains what the second command is supposed to do. Are you looking for alternatives to your `xargs` command? Is your requirement to specify the URLs as command line arguments instead of in a file? (You could easily define a shell function that does this.) Please [edit] your question to add clarification, don't use comments for this purpose.